# Github Actions - How to update more than one server?

Tags: ubuntu, github, server, github-actions

I've a working github actions workflow.
I wanna use it with 2 VPS's
I've 2 runners in idle mode and 2 Deploy Keys.

When I run a Action it only updates my first VPS and the other stays in his current state.
If I set the runner of the first server to offline the other server updates.

Is there a way that both server update simultaneously?

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'npm'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the matrix:

```
jobs:
  example_matrix:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        version: [10, 12, 14]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.version }}
```

As a matrix, you need to provide values that later your action uses as arguments to connect to VPS. To make this simultaneous.

You may read it more [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs).

Comment: Okay but i use this already (i edit my post) and it's not working for multiple server...

Comment: Is it possible for you to try your workflow with the ubuntu-latest pool to ensure the workflow works correctly?